# List of ALL Ethereum Contract Events, for ex: Transfer, Mint, etc

Tags: events

A very simple question, yet couldn't find a simple answer.

Where can I find a list of all event types such as Transfer, Mint, etc? Is this stored anywhere, for ex: online database or historically within a Geth or Parity archive node?

Thanks

Comment: There's no such list. If you're thinking of ERC20 events, then search [these contracts](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/token/ERC20).

Answer (score 1):

When logged event is stored in transaction receipt, the type of event is stored as a keccak256 hash of event signature.  The signature is a string looking like this: `Transfer(address,address,uint256)`.
You may query hashes of all event signatures, but in general there is no way to decode these hashes into plain text signatures.
All the signature hashes may be obtained from [Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) with the following request:

```sql
SELECT topics[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.logs`
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH (topics) >= 1
GROUP BY topics[OFFSET(0)];
```

Currently it returns 155021 different hashes.